# Let $A = {a \in G : a * a \neq e}$ Prove that $x \in A \iff x^{-1} \in A$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be a finite group with an even number of elements. Let $A = {a \in G : a * a \neq e}$ Prove that $x \in A \iff x^{-1} \in A$.
I have tried to construct the following argument.
$a^{-1} * a^{-1} = a^{-2}= (a^{2})^{-1}$.
Since $a * a^{-1} = e$ It follows that $a^{-2} = \frac{e}{a^2}$ Therefore $a^{-2} \neq e$. And hence $(a^{2})^{-1} \neq e$.
Is this argument correct? But what if $a^2$ is 1? Could you please help me to prove this statement.

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{e}{a^2}$ is not proper notation.

$(\Rightarrow)$ If $x\in A$ then $x*x\not=e$. Suppose, for contradiction, that $x^{-1}*x^{-1}=e$. Then $x^{-2}=e\Rightarrow (x^{2})^{-1}=e \Rightarrow x^2=e$ contradiction. Hence $x^{-1}*x^{-1}\not=e \Rightarrow x^{-1}\in A$ .

$(\Leftarrow )$ If $x^{-1}\in A$ then $x^{-1}*x^{-1}\not=e$. Following a similar argument you get $x\in A$

Comment: $(x^2)^{-1}=e \Rightarrow [(x^2)^{-1}]^{-1}=e^{-1}=e \Rightarrow x^2=e$

Answer (score 0):

Take $x \in G$ and then (using $(a * b)^{-1} = b^{-1} *a^{-1}$) observe that $$x^{-1} * x^{-1} = (x * x)^{-1}. \tag{$\star$}$$ Hence, if $x \in G \setminus A$, the right-hand side of $(\star)$ is $e^{-1} = e$, and then $x^{-1} \in G \setminus A$. Conversely, if $x^{-1} \in G \setminus A$, the left-hand side of $(\star)$ is $e$ and then $x*x = e^{-1} = e$, that is, $x \in G \setminus A$. Thus, we have shown that $x \in G \setminus A$ if and only if $x^{-1} \in G \setminus A$, which of course is the same as saying that $x \in A$ if and only if $x^{-1} \in A$.